# Sound/Player Install?

Tags: sound, dell

Cant get sound out of wired Dell speakers on Dell Studio XPS 435mt running Ubuntu 18.04 and all updates installed. When attempting to play free internet radio/video clips I receive a message saying Flash Player 10 is not installed and then the install doesnt happen. Im pretty much a novice at tweaking computer programs etc. Can anybody help me out with this one? Thanks!

Comment: Can you hear the sound when you play an mp3 file on your hard disk?

Comment: have never tried playing an mp3 file.Just trying to get internet radio/video stations to play. No sound from websites that use you tube etc

Comment: Which browser you use?

Comment: Firefox latest version

Comment: Goto Ubuntu software and search for Chromium, and install it. Try Chromium web browser and see if you can hear the sound.

Comment: Well I have installed Chromium / Google Chrome but can't actually open it.

Comment: did you update your system to the latest version?

Comment: yes.. all is up to date